# Country of residence in CV

Tags: resume

I was wondering how to include my country of residence on my resume if I am applying to a country where I am not a resident nor a citizen. (e.g.: applying to denmark as a canadian citizen living in australia)

---

v1: Nationality: Canadian - Residence: Australia

---

v2: Nationality: Canadian - Residency: Australia

---

v3: Nationality: Canadian - Country of Residence: Australia

---

By the way, is there any difference at all between the word 'residence' and 'residency'?

EDIT: I want to include my nationality because I am not an EU citizen which might be an issue.

Thanks,

Comment: I prefer v1. BUT - not sure if you should actually include nationality in this way in the CV. Might be better to mention in the cover letter if it's a possible visa issue? As for residence, if you include your address (1234 Example ... AUSTRALIA), then the fact that you reside in Australia will be self-evident.

Comment: Why would you want to list either nationality or country of residence on your resume particularly if you're applying to a job in a different country?  It would be useful to indicate whether you are authorized to work in the country or whether you would need to be sponsored for a visa.  That might be related to your nationality but it might not and you probably don't want people reading your resume to try to infer one from the other.

Comment: You may want to say "Current Residence".

Answer (score 5):

In many countries, including Canada and probably Australia and Denmark, discriminating on the basis of nationality is illegal.  A recruiter probably doesn't want to know your nationality, and shouldn't be taking it into account.

What they do want to know is whether or not you need a visa to work where the vacancy is. If you do not, then you should write something like "eligible to work for any employer in Denmark". If not then "requires visa to work in Denmark" would be appropriate.

They do also want to know where you are applying from, because they want to know how difficult it will be to interview you, and how much it will cost to move you to their location. The easiest way to do this is supply a mailing address of your current location, i.e. the place you would be travelling from to attend an interview, and where they should direct written mail (this doesn't have to be your country of residence, but usually is).

Comment: Having been in the position to hire before in Australia. No-one cares about your original nationality. If you do not have a work visa or are not located in the same country there is a good possibility that your resume will end up in the garbage unless you are amazing. If you have no work visa it is a huge hassle to sponsor you. If you are not located in the same country it makes interviewing difficult